# Raphael js, animate along path problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I have defined two circles and one path, where the path connect the center points of two circles:

```
c1=r.circle(40, 40, 20).attr(dashed);
c2=r.circle(140, 40, 20).attr(dashed);
path = r.path("m 40 40 l 100 0");
```

I would like to have the feature that when mouse click on the path line, the left circle `c1` will collapse with the right circle `c2` (that's the left circle `c1` will move to and finally join the right circle `c2`), and during this process, the **path will always connect the center points of the two circles**, that's the path will get shorter and shorter as two circles get closer.

I am not sure how to implement this feature, I tried some thing like

```
path.onclicke(){
 c1.animateAlong(path, 1000, true, function (){
   c1.attr({cx: 140, cy: 40});
 });
}
```

But I don't know how to handle the path, so that the path is getting shorter as c1 get closer to c2. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

I've done my share of wrestling with paths in the last two weeks, I assure you.  I happened to notice that .attr() and .animate() for path objects can be given an entirely new path string (see the documentation at http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.attr).  So, I mocked up your example in horrible day-glo colors and got the results I think you're looking for like this:

```
var c1 = this.canvas.circle( 300, 200, 50 ).attr( { stroke: "#F00", fill: "#F00", 'fill-opacity': 0.5, 'stroke-width': 10 } );
var c2 = this.canvas.circle( 500, 200, 50 ).attr( { stroke: "#00F", fill: "#00F", 'fill-opacity': 0.5, 'stroke-width': 10 } );
var p = this.canvas.path( "M300 200 L500 200" ).attr( { stroke: "#0F0", "stroke-width": 10 } );
p.click(    function() 
{
    c1.animate( { cx: 400, cy: 200, r: 60 }, 1500 );
    c2.animate( { cx: 400, cy: 200, r: 60 }, 1500 );
    p.animate( { path: "M400 200 L400 200", "stroke-opacity": 0.25 }, 1500 );
} );
```

Is this what you had in mind?